# Is this computation of $Xf$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $X = x \partial/\partial x + y \partial/\partial y$ be a vector field and $ f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$. Compute $Xf$.

$Xf$ is defined by $(Xf)(p) = X(p) f$ for all $p \in U$ or - writing $X$ in the base decomposition $X = \sum a^i \partial/\partial x^i$:

$$ Xf = \sum a^i \partial f/\partial x^i $$

My solution:

Let $(x,y,z) \in U$. Then,

$$ (Xf)(x,y,z) = x \partial/\partial x^1 + y \partial/\partial x^2 = 2x^2 + 2y^2,$$

i.e. $f(x,y,z) \overset{X}{\mapsto} 2x^2+2y^2$.

I‘m very new to this topic - is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct........

Comment: this $(Xf)(x,y,z) = x \partial/\partial x^1 + y \partial/\partial x^2 $ is not right, as $Xf$ is an scalar function, not a vector field

Comment: @Masacroso it has to be $\partial f/\partial x (x,y,z) + \partial f/\partial y (x,y,z)$ right?

Comment: using Einstein summation convention, if $X=X^j \frac{\partial}{\partial r^j}$ then $Xf=X^j \frac{\partial}{\partial r^j}f$